# Django:Redirect after login success

Tags: django, redirect

I  write a function about login. like below:

```
def login(request,template_name="login/login.html"):

    res = {}
    if(request.method == "POST"):
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        user = auth.authenticate(username=username,password=password)

        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                auth.login(request,user)
                redirect_to = reverse("home")
                return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_to)

    return render_to_response(template_name,RequestContext(request,res))
```

if the login check is successful, it redirect to my home page .
my problem is,it shows the correct page content. 
but the URL is error. it is stay on the login url.

how to show the redirect page URL?

the HTML code is:

```
<form class="authenticate" action="{{ next }}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table border="0">
        {{ login_form }}
    </table>
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="login" />
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
    <input type="submit" id="login-btn" value="login" />
</form>
```

The urls.py is:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^$','mypro.views.home',name='home'),
url(r'^login/',include('login.urls')),
url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)


urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^$','login.views.login',name="login"),
url(r'^logout/$','login.views.logout',name="logout"),
 )
```

I find that both firebug's response and html show "Reload the page to get source for: http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8002/h5acr/login/refresh/" .
how to reload the page ?

Comment: I add them in the above

Comment: That code should redirect to home and change the url as well. Are you missing some other info here? Does `HttpResponseRedirect()` is called?

Comment: if login is successful. i call HttpResponseRedirect().i also test redirect() and HttpResponsePermanentRedirect(). they  also cannot redirect to the correct url address

Answer (score 0):

In your login form, the action should be the login url, not `next`.

```
<form class="authenticate" action="{% url 'login' %}" method="post">
```

Comment: Even if that doesn't fix the problem, you should make this change. The login data should be posted to the login page. Hope you manage to solve your problem.

Comment: I got it,thank you. I found that it is not caused by redirect itself.when the browser send request to get my goal url. it show "Reload the page to get source for: http://54.250.167.254:8002/h5acr/home/". how can i reload it?

Comment: I've not come across that error before. If you update your answer to include the error rather than adding it as a comment, then more people will see, it.

Comment: I finally solved the problem！！ It caused by JMB Frame

Comment: @Daney What is JMB Frame?  I'm having this same issue and can't figure out what is going on.